# Setting text dynamically of EditText

Tags: java, android

I am unable to figure out how to set text dynamically of an EditText. A fellow user at stackoverflow suggested me to use `onTextChanged()` but I don't how that either.So I read on it for an hour and when tried to implement it,Errors Errors Errors!
So,I am asking this question again.

I have two `EditTexts` et1 and et2. Both are of type `NumberDecimal`.et2 is `unfocusable` and `unclickable`.The user can only input value in et1.What I want is that as soon as user enters a number in et1,that number should pe displayed in et2.So,if the user has to enter 10,he will first enter 1 and that 1 should also be displayed in et2.Now to complete the number,he will enter 0 and then the number 10 should be displayed in et2.So,et2 should be updated character by character depending upon the entry made in et1.

This is how I read from et1 :

```
et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
String read=et1.getText().toString();
if(read.length()!=0)
{
float a=Float.parseFloat(read);
}
```

Now if I use `setText()` on et2,that wont be dynamic and furthermore I will have to make use of an `button` to show the text in et2 and it will show whole `String` which was entered in et1 until the button was clicked.

Using `Listener` on et1 is an good idea but I don't know its implementation with `onTextChanged` since I am a newbie.

Please help.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
final TextView et2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView et1 = new TextView(this){
            @Override
            protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,
                    int before, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
                et2.setText(this.getText());
            }
        };
```

now add these et1,et2 to any layout.

Comment: this can't be used with EditTexts?

Comment: It can be added in the sameway.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing you are trying to do, I used a KeyListener. Just update the EditText everytime a key is pressed.

Check it out:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html